# Grails acegi plugin

Tags: grails, groovy

I installed acegi.

So, then i run `grails create-auth-domains User Role Requestmap`, it didn't create any domain class. Why?

This is my console show:

```
E:\Grails\Linh> grails create-auth-domains User Role Requestmap
Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: D:\Grails\grails-1.3.7

Base Directory: E:\Grails\Linh
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 715ms.
Running script C:\Users\My\.grails\1.3.7\projects\Linh\plugins\acegi-0.5.3.2\scripts\CreateAuthDomains.groovy
Environment set to development
     [copy] Copying 1 resource to E:\Grails\Linh
    [unjar] Expanding: E:\Grails\Linh\grails-shared-files.jar into E:\Grails\Linh
   [delete] Deleting: E:\Grails\Linh\grails-shared-files.jar
     [copy] Copying 1 resource to E:\Grails\Linh
    [unjar] Expanding: E:\Grails\Linh\grails-app-files.jar into E:\Grails\Linh
   [delete] Deleting: E:\Grails\Linh\grails-app-files.jar
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the plugin is installed correctly? Can you run `grails list-plugins -installed` and tell us if acegi is present?

Comment: Any reason you're using a plugin which specifically states [on it's information page](http://grails.org/plugin/acegi) `Development on this plugin has stopped. You're encouraged to use the new Spring Security Core plugin instead which is the official Grails security plugin and will be actively maintained. `

Comment: @user1024858 Have a little patience; you can't *expect* free help in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem recently, like one of the comments stated you don't really want to use the acegi-plugin, you want to use the [Spring security core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core)

Tip:
If you're looking to hash and/or salt your passwords [this](http://blog.swwomm.com/2010/06/grails-passwords-salted.html) is a great tutorial!

Good luck!